# ITMS-90535 Unable to publish libgdx iOS app

Tags: ios, libgdx, google-play-games, google-signin, robovm

I get the this errors when I try to publish my libgdx app to apple app store.
I'm using Xcode 7.1.1 and installed latest Google Play Games/Google SignIn Robopods (1.9.1-SNAPSHOT)

> 1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
>   /var/folders/n8/2_pl6r9x61vbm3mz4jm8ykz40000gn/T/884F2253-C7E5-4E8C-B429-5C4551C6306F/982835004.itmsp
>   - Error Messages: ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/IOSLauncher.app/GooglePlus.bundle' does
>   not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not
>   contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key
>   from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this
>   bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the
>   developer of the framework for an update to address this issue." ERROR
>   ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/IOSLauncher.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle'
>   does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally
>   does not contain an executable, consider removing the
>   CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a
>   CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party
>   framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an
>   update to address this issue." ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected
>   CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/IOSLauncher.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle'
>   does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally
>   does not contain an executable, consider removing the
>   CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a
>   CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party
>   framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an
>   update to address this issue." ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected
>   CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/IOSLauncher.app/gpg.bundle' does not contain a bundle
>   executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an
>   executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is
>   part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of
>   the framework for an update to address this issue."

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the `CFBundleExecutable` from the offending info.plist inside the bundle.

Comment: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/863   this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**From Armend answers**
You have to delete the key `"CFBundleExecutable"` from 
`"Pods/Pods/GooglePlayGames/Resources/gpg.bundle/info.plist"`.

but to show the Key `"CFBundleExecutable"` in this file

1. First press right click and switch `"show Raw Keys/Values"`.
2. Then Right Click and cut `CFBundleExecutable`.

Then it will work fine.

Otherwise, you can use updated PlayGames plugin 0.9.30. It will also help.

Related Link: [ERROR ITMS-90535 gpg.bundle #863](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/863)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a similar issue on mine. I didn't realize that the Info.plist file with the problem was one created by a cocoa pod (I had on first instinct deleted the CFBundleKey from my main Info.plist which will only give you another error).

For instance, yours references the `Payload/IOSLauncher.app/GooglePlus.bundle`, so go to the offending place and fix that plist by deleting the CFBundleKey like the error says. Mine was pointing to a plist within one of the pods.